# Connect to Oracle database on a different server from PHP

Tags: php, oracle, database-connection, oci8

Hello I have a database engine sitting on a remote server, while my webserver is present locally. I have worked pretty much with client-server architecture, where the server has both the webserver and the database engine. Now I need to connect to an Oracle database which is situated on a different server.

Can anybody give me any suggestions?? I believe ODBC_CONNECT might not work. Do I use OCI8 drivers?? How would I connect to my database server.

Also I would have a very high number of database calls going back and forth, so is it good to go with persistent connection or do I still use individual database calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ODBC, then you need to use the PHP's [ODBC driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) rather than the OCI8 driver. Otherwise, you need the Oracle client installed on your webserver (even if it's just Oracle's Instant Client) and then you can use OCI8.

**EDIT**

Personally I wouldn't recommend persistent connections. While there is a slowdown when connecting to a database (especially a remote database), persistent connections can cause more issues if you have a high hit count (exceeding the number of persistent connections available), or if there's a network hiccup of any kind that leaves orphaned connections on the database, and potentially orphaned pconnectiosn as well.

Comment: Ok! how does my code change if I have the instant client on my webserver?? would that client be GUI?? I have never worked with an Oracle database. Could you please explain a little.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle client comes for each platform. In summary it is collection of needed files to talk to oracle and a command line utility for oracle. Just go to oracle.com and downloads